# Is there a curse associated with misuse of Tantra?

Tags: agamas, tantra, curse

I have heard that Tantra has a curse associated with it; that any misuse will lead to Naraka.

> rauravaM cha pade pade
>
> *"In every step you take a very great hell by the name raurava awaits the practitioner"*

Can someone give a detailed reference of this?

Comment: You added reference in the question right?  Where are you quoting from? It is true that misuse of Tantra or not following it properly will be dangerous. Not afterlife but in this life itself.

Comment: I have heard that shlokA; that's why I am asking for a detail reference. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Also misuse of anything will give a bad result, but it's more about a curse on the whole Tantra system.

Comment: Is that related to Ashtama Siddhi?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS No it's not related to Ashthama Siddhi.

Comment: maybe parashurama kalpa sutra

Comment: @Rakesh add that to your answer

Answer (score 4):

I did NOT find "pade pade"

However, misuse of Tantra is criticised by many Tantrik Scriptures and scholars with the warning or curse of going to Naraka or hell.

The Kaulavalinirnaya says:

> kuladharmam samaashritya aacharam yo na paalayet/yathechchhacharinastasya mahaapaatakinah sadaa/**niskritir naasti tasyaiva mahaarauravasamkule/ sa mahaapashutyukto devataashaapam apnyuat.**

meaning: He, who does whatever he wishes and dooes not follow the rituals after accepting the Kauladharma, is cursed by the deity. He is a wretched beast and can not escape the **raurava-hell**.(Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Saktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, vol. 1, page 612.

According to the Purascharyarnava:

> If a brahmin is willing to get siddhi by the vama-marga, he will go to hell. ( Ibid. page 605).

According to Niruttara-Tantra,

> Someone entering the kula-marga without knowing the kaula hints, must go to the dangerous hale in this birth, not to tell of next biths!(Ibid, page 610)

Rameswara writes in Parasurama-Kalpasutra-vritti:

> Those who exploit the opportunities of drinking wine without scriptural restrictions, suffer severly after death in hells.( Ibid page 598).

Such evil end is mentioned for the ones who do the Abhichaara Karma (Vasikarana, Akarshana,stambhana,vidweshana, Uchchhatana and Maarana) for fulfilling narrow self-interest. The Kularnava-Tantra says:

> The aspirants are very eager to earn money. Shiva kills him. As dry grass is destroyed by fire, Shiva's rage destroys everything of him.(Ref:Ibid,vol 2,page 1066)

Kaularnava-Tantra also mentions the Akaula-Tantras as Paapasatras. Shiva says in Kularnava-Tantra:

> People practice these Pashu-sastras because of sin. They are bound to remain lowly for hundred kalpas.(Ibid page 1067)

Answer (score 3):

This verse is a famous one from KulArnava tantra/parashurAma kalpa sutra.

It says that path of tantra (kaulam) is not at all easy and is like walking on a sharp sword. Any time you slip then you reserve your place in raurava hell.

This is a warning to the sadhakas that only brave and sincere people must adopt it. Because there are instances where people have fallen from the path (yoga bhrastha). So those who try to misuse it in anyway and just enter for wrong intention then it would bring bad result to them.

This verse is more of a warning for aspirants and also reminder for those who already in the path not to go astray.

Comment: Which verse of Kularnava exactly? The verse u are talking about (walking on sharp sword) is there in Chapter2. But thr "rauravam cha pade pade" is not found.

Comment: @Rickross May be in Parashurama kalpa sutra